# Vector Sum Reduction

Tags: summation, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, jacobian

I’m currently reading Jeremy Howard’s paper [“The Matrix Calculus You Need For Deep Learning”](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01528) and came across a bit I don’t understand.

In section 4.4 (Vector Sum Reduction), they are calculating the derivative of $y = \operatorname{sum}(\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}))$, like so:
\begin{align*}
     \frac{\partial y}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
  &= \left[
       \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_1},
       \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_2},
       \dotsc,
       \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_n}
     \right] \\
  &= \left[
       \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \sum_i f_i(\mathbf{x}) ,
       \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} \sum_i f_i(\mathbf{x}),
       \dotsc,
       \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \sum_i f_i(\mathbf{x})
     \right] \\
  &= \left[
       \sum_i \frac{\partial f_i(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_1},
       \sum_i \frac{\partial f_i(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_2},
       \dotsc,
       \sum_i \frac{\partial f_i(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_n}
     \right] \\
\end{align*}
(Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ0Os.png).)

Here, the following is noted:

> Notice we were careful here to leave the parameter as a vector $\mathbf{x}$ because each function $f_i$ could use all values in the vector, not just $x_i$.

What does that mean? I thought it meant that we can’t reduce $f_i(\mathbf{x})$ to $f_i(x_i)$ to $x_i$, but right afterwards, that is precisely what they do:

> Let’s look at the gradient of the simple $y = \operatorname{sum}(\mathbf{x})$.
>   The function inside the summation is just $f_i(\mathbf{x}) = x_i$ and the gradient is then:
>   \begin{align*}
>      \nabla y
>   &= \left[
>        \sum_i \frac{\partial f_i(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_1},
>        \sum_i \frac{\partial f_i(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_2},
>        \dotsc,
>        \sum_i \frac{\partial f_i(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_n}
>      \right] \\
>   &= \left[
>        \sum_i \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_1},
>        \sum_i \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_2},
>        \dotsc,
>        \sum_i \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_n}
>      \right].
> \end{align*}
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5QdJ.png).)

Does it have something to do with the summation being taken out? Or am I reading this completely wrong?

Comment: It's reminding you that in general $f_i(\textbf x)=f_i(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ is a function of all the variables $x_j$. Then they do a **particular** example where $f_i(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=x_i$ just depends on the one variable.

Comment: Ohh got it! Thank you!